# Spring java config EJB proxy not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ejb-3.0

I have a problem getting EJB beans working when using Spring's java config classes.
Specifically I have the following that works:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.web.config")
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:spring-beans.xml"})
public class AppConfig {
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
   // basic Spring MVC setup omitted
}
```

My spring-beans.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <jee:local-slsb id="fooService" jndi-name="java:app/model/FooServiceBean!com.company.ejb.FooService"
      business-interface="com.company.ejb.FooService" />
</beans>
```

With this configuration, everything works, and I can do this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private final FooService fooService;

    @Autowired
    public MyPageController(FooService fooService){
        this.fooService = fooService;
    }

    // request methods
}
```

Now i try to get rid of the XML file. According to [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#ejb-access-local) the local-slsb should be equivalent

```
<bean id="fooService"
        class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:app/model/FooServiceBean!com.company.ejb.FooService"/>
    <property name="businessInterface" value="com.company.ejb.FooService"/>
</bean>
```

However, if I remove the `@ImportResource` from `AppConfig` and put this `@Bean` method instead, deployment fails because the Controller cannot be instantiated (no autowire candidates found for `FooService`):

```
@Bean
    public LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean fooService(){
        LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean factory = new LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setBusinessInterface(FooService.class);
        factory.setJndiName("java:app/model/FooServiceBean!com.company.ejb.FooService");
        return factory;
    }
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? I am using Spring version 4.0.2.

Comment: explain `doesn't work`

Comment: I already did? Deployment fails because it cannot instantiate my Controller. The exception says no autowire candidates were found for FooService.

Comment: Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: I updated the question. I use Spring 4.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue was related to the order in which configuration was read, and possibly double configuration loading.

Specifically, introducing a separate configuration class and importing it before WebConfig seems to do the trick, like so:

```
@Configuration
@Import({EJBConfig.class, WebConfig.class})
public class AppConfig {
}

@Configuration
public class EJBConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean fooService(){
        LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean factory = new LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setBusinessInterface(FooService.class);
        factory.setJndiName("java:app/model/FooServiceBean!com.company.ejb.FooService");
        return factory;
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
   // basic Spring MVC setup omitted
}
```